# Freeing memory outside scope of a pointer

Tags: c, pointers

For example:

```
char** fn() {
    char *x = (char *) malloc(10 * sizeof(char));
    char **y = (char **) malloc(2 * sizeof(char *));
    gets(x);
    y[0] = x;
    y[1] = &x[5];
    return y;
}

int main() {
    char **p = fn();
    printf("%s, %s\n", p[0], p[1]);
    free(p);
    return 0;
}
```

Now, I freed the memory allocated to y with `free(p)`. But that didn't free the memory allocated to `x`. I can't free it in `fn()` because `y[0]` and `y[1]` are still pointing to it and will be used.

So how do I free the memory allocated to `x`?

Comment: With `free(p[0])` like you assigned it, but in reverse order *before* `free(p)`.

Comment: @WeatherVane Is this because it refers to the same starting address? Wouldn't you need to know how much memory was malloc'd? p[0] doesn't seem to have any "record" of that.

Comment: Why don't you use `x + 5` instead of `&x[5]`

Comment: @SomeName Stylistic preference, I guess. I find it easier to understand. Is the former preferred for any reason?

Comment: @NamanSood that's completely the same. I just asked. :)

Comment: Yes, it is because you allocated memory to `x` and then assigned that to the array element with `y[0] = x;` The important information for `free` is an actual address that was returned by `malloc` etc, regardless of where it is stored. The record of how much memory was allocated is stored internally by the system. You know how much, because it was you who allocated it.

Comment: @WeatherVane Got it, thanks! If you'd like to consolidate your comments into an answer, I'd be happy to mark it accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You allocated memory to `x` and then assigned that to the array element

```
char *x = (char *) malloc(10 * sizeof(char));
//...
y[0] = x;
```

So you can release the memory in the same way but in reverse order

```
free(p[0]);
free(p);
```

The important information for `free` is an actual address that was returned by `malloc` etc, regardless of where it is stored. The record of how much memory was allocated is stored internally by the system. You know how much, because it was you who allocated it.